# Excel connections not all refreshing

Tags: excel, refresh

I have an Excel file with 4 sheets.  Each sheet is pulling data from a different SQL stored procedure.  I have created a button that refreshes the connection for each sheet.  It works perfectly on everyone's PC . . . except for one.  When you click the button on this particular person's PC, it only refreshes 3 out of 4 sheets.  No error message shows up.  We each have our on local copy of this Excel file.  I even gave her a copy of mine and it only refreshes 3 out of 4.  I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: do any of the queries rely on the results of another? Such as for a parameter.

Comment: It accepts 2 parameters that come from 2 cells, which is passed to the sp's.

Comment: Oh, and none of the queries rely on the results of any other query.  The 2 cells which provide the parameters for the sp's are just directly entered by the user.

Comment: Does it work if you Right click on the query that doesn't work and manually refresh it? How about if you Refresh All?

Comment: That's a negative Houston.